# Is it Necessary to move from neo4j Community Edition to Enterprise Edition and Queries about creating a new database in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am doing Research work on Neo4j graph database. My main purpose to use Neo4j is  for searching purpose.Till now I am working on the community edition of it, I had read (have a doubt) somewhere it allows around 100 millions of nodes. I had a conception till now that it will work for me but now I am confused.

***My Module:-***
Ex -- It will be like question asked by users there will be tags of that question and the level of question. Nodes will be created of question,tag and level and interconnected with relation between them.There will be some other modules also. So, day by day the size of graph will increase only.

**MY QUESTONS:-**

1. Am I going on a right approach to use Neo4j for searching purpose?
2. Limitation of community edition for our production mode of our website.
3. Is it necessary to move from community to enterprise edition for website in production?

Currently, As per the coding part I am using neo4j-jdbc drivers with cypher queries.as suggested to me from a renowned user of SO only. 
**QUERY** -*- IS it okay to work on default db or we have to create a new one after the certain size of the db?*

Answer (score 10):

1. Yes. (but I might be biased)
2. For a detailed list of feature comparison on Community vs. Enterprise edition see http://neo4j.com/editions/. The most important feature of Enterprise edition is clustering (for high availability and read scale out) and online backups. There are no differences in terms of capacity or cypher language (except property exist constraints).
3. Legally no, you can perfectly run community in production as long as you comply to GPL license. There are basically 3 reasons to go for enterprise: 1) you need one of the enterprise features from the comparison document above, 2) you need commercial support with guaranteed SLAs or access to consulting services from the vendor, 3) you require indemnity protection.

Comment: One more QUERY -- IS it okay to work on default db or we have to create a new one after the certain size of the db?

Comment: Depends on your usage model. In most cases using one graphdb instance to rule 'em all is the way to go.

Comment: Thankyou sir. Sir any other way to stay connected to you for any query purpose.

Comment: "There are no differences in terms of capacity..." This statement is not true, community is limited to 34B nodes.